# change css by using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am getting a problem while using .css method of jQuery. when I change current div background color on some event then it changes for a moment like a second and again shows the same background color of div.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="super"> 
 <div id="parent"> 
  <form>
   <input type="text" id="in"/>
  </form> 
  </div>
 </div> 
</div> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("form").submit(function() {
   $("#parent").css("background","yellow"); 
 });     
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: <body>  
<div id="super">  
<div id="parent">  
<form>  
<input type="text" id="in"/>  
</form>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("form").submit(function() {  
$("#parent").css("background","yellow");  
});   
});  

</script>  
</body>                                                                                                                                          This is the code when i submit the form it should change the parent bgcolor to yellow.It shows yellow for a second and regain previous bgcolor. Hopw this helps you.

Comment: So you're changing the background colour on submit? When does it change back to the original colour? When the page reloads? That makes perfect sense. DOM modifications won't persist over page reloads...

Comment: Why would you use a form that doesn't submit anything (and ultimately does *nothing*) just to change the background color? You can achieve the same effect with, well, with most anything on `click`.

Comment: but I dont want any button on my web page Here I just write something on text box and press enter and I got the required change in css

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the css on submit.  This means that it only changes when you submit the form, but submitting the form, because there is no `action`, it redirects to itself (default).  Your browser then loads the page with it's default style sheet.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be to add a 'return false;' directly after setting the background colour.

The full code would look like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="super">
        <div id="parent">
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="in">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("form").submit(function() { 
            $("#parent").css("background","yellow"); 
            return false; 
        });   
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

UPDATE: This is how you would do it with e.preventDefault() as recommended in Richard's comment:

(note that you must add a single named parameter (in this case I used 'e') to the submit event handler which passes through the actual **Event** as an object).

```
<body>
    <div id="super">
        <div id="parent">
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="in">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("form").submit(function(e) { 
            $("#parent").css("background","yellow"); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });   
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

I would recommend going with the e.preventDefault() route for future code consistencies sake.

Comment: ... or, since we're already using jQuery, just call `e.preventDefault()` inside the `submit` handler (provided we pass it in, like `.submit(function (e) { }`. `return false;` is soooo DOM0. :D

Comment: jQuery allows you to do a lot of old-school javascript really easily. In this case return false just prevents the default behaviour of a form submit from happening. A bit of background, certain elements in HTML/javascript have default behaviours. Clicking a link will open a new page and submitting a form will load the new page with the form fields processed. You can cancel this default behaviour using return false inline like so: <form action="" onsubmit="return false;">..</form>. Richards suggestion of e.preventDefault() is a good way of cancelling the default behaviour of click/submit event.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `onclick="return false;"` on your form's submit button? If not, the jQuery changes the bg color and you see that while the new page is loading. Once the page reloads, it will of course revert back to original color.

Comment: I'm not usually one to be such a spastic nazi about it, but why would you use inline JS `onclick` hooks when you're already using something like jQuery? Even more so, the asker already has a fully functioning handler hook using `.submit()`, so while this (more or less) leads to the (more or less) correct idea, it's an arguably bad way of getting to the point.

Comment: for not usually being so, you're pretty good at it. I guess I was generally stating what the fix was. I guess using `onclick` is just a habit when handling forms. I know it's probably a bad one. Anyway, the point I was trying to get across is the same as everyone else's. Your form is being submitted and hence reloading the page.

Comment: Why thank you. I do try so very hard. :) But seriously, I meant no offense. Just pointing something out, but like I said, I do recognize where you were getting at. We all want to be better programmers, so let's just think of it as unsolicited advice.

Comment: haha I didn't really take any offense. I saw that he had already used the `.submit()` hook after I posted the answer, but for some reason felt I had made the point I was trying to make. I probably should have gone back and corrected myself. In any case, @mattlangtree has proposed the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing will work, but if you're not submitting a form, you shouldn't hook onto that event.

From a user's perspective, you just want the user to be able to press enter and have the background change?  You can do this:

```
// note, if you only want the user to do this in the the textbox, 
// just change the selector from 'document' to whatever the textbox is.
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (13 == e.which) {
        $("#parent").css("background","yellow");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.So here 13 is for "ENTER" key right?...I am wondering do i still need to write e.preventDefault();

Comment: If you, for some reason, want the 'enter' keypress to still register, then you can omit that line.  The only reason, though, is if you had a textarea control somewhere on your form.